# Hello world in Node.js

Tags: node.js, special-characters

I am trying to start off with node.js. Just wrote

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

in a HelloWorld.js file and tried to run

node HelloWorld.js on the terminal. I see the following error:

```
/Users/arkidmitra/Desktop/NodeJs/helloworld.js:1
��c
^

node.js:134
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:399:25)
    at Object..js (module.js:410:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:423:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
```

I wrote it in simple textedit. I can see some special characters in the file. What is the possible problem and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try using a different editor.

I quite like [Kod](http://kodapp.com/), even though it's a bit buggy.

If you want something more stable, [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) should be good.

Also, you should delete and rewrite (not copy and paste) the file, to get rid of the unwanted characters.

Comment: Delete the original file, and rewrite it.

Comment: Delete and rewrote in vi. Worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Delete the file and write it again with a different text editor...

Comment: vi. But for the moment you can do `echo console.log\(\"Hello World\"\); > test.js`